# OpenGL, How do I disable glutSpecialFunc after I reach a target?

Tags: c++, opengl

We are making a Maze sort of program in OpenGL, and we allow the user to use the arrow keys in order to move a destination on the screen. When the user reaches that destination using the arrow keys, I want to disable the user from being able to use the keyboard anymore. Is there a way I can do some sort of glutSpecialFunc.disable? Here is where I want to put the disable in this if statement:

```
void myKeyboard(int keys, int x, int y){

switch(keys){ ...
    }
    if(location == G.source){
    cout<<"\nYou have completed the game";
    drawShortestPath();
  /* Enter disable code here */ 
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

You could simply toggle a boolean value when the player reaches the target/destination, and check that boolean value in your `myKeyboard()` function.

```
bool game_done = false;

void myKeyboard(int keys, int x, int y) {
    if (!game_done) {
        switch(keys) {
            // ... the rest of your code ...
        }
    }
}
```

Then when the player reaches the target/destination simply say `game_done = true;`

Instead of calling the boolean `game_done` you could instead call it something like `lock_keyboard` that would probably make more sense overall.

Then if you want to "activate" the keyboard again you simply toggle the boolean value again (set it to false)